# Permutation feature importance

Tags: python, machine-learning

What is the difference between feature importance and Permutation feature importance? And how can we compute the scores of feature importance in python?

Comment: Please clarify your question, and ensure it isn’t too broad and remains on-topic. See: [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

Here you can get some info:

[Algorithm section:](http://The%20idea%20is%20the%20following:%20feature%20importance%20can%20be%20measured%20by%20looking%20at%20how%20much%20the%20score%20(accuracy,%20F1,%20R%5E2,%20etc.%20-%20any%20score%20we%E2%80%99re%20interested%20in)%20decreases%20when%20a%20feature%20is%20not%20available.%20%20To%20do%20that%20one%20can%20remove%20feature%20from%20the%20dataset,%20re-train%20the%20estimator%20and%20check%20the%20score.%20But%20it%20requires%20re-training%20an%20estimator%20for%20each%20feature,%20which%20can%20be%20computationally%20intensive.%20Also,%20it%20shows%20what%20may%20be%20important%20within%20a%20dataset,%20not%20what%20is%20important%20within%20a%20concrete%20trained%20model.%20%20To%20avoid%20re-training%20the%20estimator%20we%20can%20remove%20a%20feature%20only%20from%20the%20test%20part%20of%20the%20dataset,%20and%20compute%20score%20without%20using%20this%20feature.%20It%20doesn%E2%80%99t%20work%20as-is,%20because%20estimators%20expect%20feature%20to%20be%20present.%20So%20instead%20of%20removing%20a%20feature%20we%20can%20replace%20it%20with%20random%20noise%20-%20feature%20column%20is%20still%20there,%20but%20it%20no%20longer%20contains%20useful%20information.%20This%20method%20works%20if%20noise%20is%20drawn%20from%20the%20same%20distribution%20as%20original%20feature%20values%20(as%20otherwise%20estimator%20may%20fail).%20The%20simplest%20way%20to%20get%20such%20noise%20is%20to%20shuffle%20values%20for%20a%20feature,%20i.e.%20use%20other%20examples%E2%80%99%20feature%20values%20-%20this%20is%20how%20permutation%20importance%20is%20computed.%20%20The%20method%20is%20most%20suitable%20for%20computing%20feature%20importances%20when%20a%20number%20of%20columns%20(features)%20is%20not%20huge;%20it%20can%20be%20resource-intensive%20otherwise.) https://eli5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/blackbox/permutation_importance.html#algorithm

and here

[Sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/inspection/plot_permutation_importance.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-inspection-plot-permutation-importance-py)